# C#: Should a nested class in a generic class be considered generic?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

```
namespace GenericsTest
{
    public class AGenericClass<T>
    {
        public class NestedNonGenericClass
        {
        }
    }
}
```

In the example above, should `NestedNonGenericClass` be considered a generic class?

The reflection API says it's a generic class, and even hands me the template parameters of the containing class as the template parameters of the nested class.

```
Type nestedClass = typeof(AGenericClass<int>.NestedNonGenericClass);
Console.Out.WriteLine("IsGeneric: {0}\tHasGenericArguments: {1}", 
   nestedClass.IsGenericType, nestedClass.GetGenericArguments().Length > 0);
```

This prints out:

> IsGeneric: True HasGenericArguments:
>   True

I don't completely agree with this behaviour. Even if the compiler generates a generic type for `NestedNonGenericClass`, I'd like to know if it's a generic because it was declared so, or because it's container is generic.

So, my question is:

Firstly, do you think it's okay to consider a nested class generic because it's container was generic? Why / Why not?

Secondly, do you happen to know some other API that can help me identify only the classes that were declared generic?

P.S: I could not find anything related to this in the ECMA specs for generics (or probably I just glossed over it).

--EDIT--

To add a little more context, I'm working on a sort of Code Generator. And I'm using the reflection API to determine whether a type is generic.

I ran into an issue with `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.KeyCollection`.

For `KeyCollection`, the reflection API says that it's generic and hands me over `TKey` and `TValue` which were declared in the container. So, the generator ends up generating `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.KeyCollection<Tkey, TValue>`

The only way I could solve this was by matching up the nested class' template parameters against the container's and eliminating all those that match. But I was wondering if there's a better approach.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In short, yes - a type inherits the type arguments from any types that contain it: this is the key to things like `List<T>.Enumerator` and many other scenarios, etc - it is critical that they share the `T` from the outer class (not just any `T`).

The ECMA ref is §25.1:

> Any class nested inside a generic
>   class declaration or a generic struct
>   declaration (§25.2) is itself a
>   generic class declaration, since type
>   parameters for the containing type
>   shall be supplied to create a
>   constructed type.

Comment: Thanks :) That answers my question. 
But is there a way to distinguish between the classes that were declared with generic templates vs. classes that just inherited generic templates from the container?

Comment: Well, you could see how many type parameters the containing type has (recursing if necessary) and compare that with the number of type parameters in the nested type.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm currently doing. But I was hoping for a better approach. Matching up template parameters against the containing class somehow feels a bit ugly :D

Comment: @Jon, recursing wouldn't be needed since the containing type would already interit of its containers' type parameters.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, your nested class absolutely is generic, because T is bound to a type (this is known as a **closed generic**) within the scope of any instance of the nested class.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class AGenericClass<T> {
    public class NestedNonGenericClass {
        public void DoSomething() {
            Console.WriteLine("typeof(T) == " + typeof(T));
        }
    }
}

public class MyClass {
    public static void Main()   {
        var c = new AGenericClass<int>.NestedNonGenericClass();
        var d = new AGenericClass<DateTime>.NestedNonGenericClass();
        c.DoSomething();
        d.DoSomething();
        Console.ReadKey(false); 
    }

}
```

The same `DoSomething()` method is producing different output depending on how the generic type was closed - so yes, the inner class is definitely exhibiting generic behaviour.

Comment: Yeah, I agree that the inner class displays generic behaviour. But is there a nice way to find out if a type became generic because of the container?

Answer (score 2):

If your not going to use T in NestedNonGenericClass you could just place it outside the class and make it private.. then it would not be Generic....

Comment: I'm working on a Code Generator (sort of)..

I ran into this problem with Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.KeyCollection

Because the reflection API returns the container's template parameters, my generator ends up generating Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.KeyCollection<TKey, TValue> :(

Answer (score 2):

The way that I choose to understand it is, when you use a generic type, C# generates everything in that type. So really, if I were to visualise what would be generated if I used AGenericClass and AGenericClass from your example above, you'd end up with two copies of the nested class:

```
public class AGenericClass<int>
{
    public class NestedNonGenericClass
    {
    }
}

public class AGenericClass<float>
{
    public class NestedNonGenericClass
    {
    }
}
```

Because of that, I would consider the nested class a generic class, as there are two versions of it, one called AGenericClass<int>.NestedNonGenericClass and another called AGenericClass<float>.NestedNonGenericClass. So really, it is like you did explicitly specify that the nested class was a generic as well. This behaviour can be very useful if you're wanting the nested class to adapt to the generic type.

However, I have found it annoying that I can no longer use nested classes in the same kind of way I do on normal classes. I can't remember the exact example anymore I'm sorry, but I know that once I had to move a class out of a generic so that I could use it as intended from other places in the code. It went against the usual pattern which I had been using for nested classes and so I didn't like it, but it was the only way. So I can understand if you might disagree with the way this is done, but to be honest, I think the way it's done is the clearest way. I mean, it's very clear to you and to the compiler that, if you move the nested class outside and just have it as a regular class, that you don't want the compiler to generate it as a generic. I don't think they could improve on this.